# How to make the CPR plots all dot until the end of session

Tags: pine-script-v4

This Indicator from Tradingview plots CPR when a new session of day trade begins, it plots one dot per new bar:

```
//@version=4
study(title="SD - Central Pivot Range - Daily Weekly Monthly Yearly", shorttitle="[SD]CPR", overlay=true)

daily_cpr = input(title="Number of Daily CPR Back", type=input.integer, defval=7, minval=0)
weekly_cpr = input(title="Number of Weekly CPR Back", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)
monthly_cpr = input(title="Number of Monthly CPR Back", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)
yearly_cpr = input(title="Number of Yearly CPR Back", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=0)


new_bar(res) =>
    change(time(res)) != 0
new_period(condition, src) =>
    result = 0.0
    result := condition ? src : result[1]
    result

pivot = (high + low + close) / 3.0
bc = (high + low) / 2.0
tc = pivot - bc + pivot


//Daily Central Pivot Range
dpp = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', pivot[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dbc = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', bc[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dtc = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', tc[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
new_day = daily_cpr > 0 and timenow - time < one_day * daily_cpr and new_bar("D")
dpp_ = new_period(new_day, dpp)
dtc_ = new_period(new_day, dtc)
dbc_ = new_period(new_day, dbc)

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? dtc_ >= dbc_ ? dtc_ : dbc_ : na, title="Daily TC", style=plot.style_circles, color=#238859, linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? dpp_ : na, title="Daily PP", style=plot.style_circles, color=#238859, linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? dtc_ >= dbc_ ? dbc_ : dtc_ : na, title="Daily BC", style=plot.style_circles, color=#238859, linewidth=2)
```

I would like that at any given timeframe (at least <1D), when entering a new session, the CPR plots all the dot until the end of the session (on this example it is daily, so it plots until the end of daily, weekly/monthly CPR does the same concepts, plots the dot until the end of the week/month) if entering a new session. How to implement this plot concept?